# how to include and exclude string from a script

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to write a script to check the log , if any line in the log have the string in include_list.txt but do not have the string in exclude_list.txt , then send alert mail to administrator , as below example , the line 2 have the string "string 4" ( which is in include_list.txt ) but do not have anything in exclude_list.txt , then display line 1 only in alert mail .

Would advise how to write this script ? very thanks .

## vi exclude_list.txt

```
 string 1
 string 2
 string 3
```

## vi include_list.txt

```
 string 4
 string 5
 string 6
```

## For example

```
 xxx string 4 xxxstring 2
 xxx string 4 xxxxxxxxxx
 xxx xxxxxxx xxxstring 3
```

Comment: Please explain the logic with you question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` piped with another `grep` for this:

```
grep -iFf includes file.log | grep -iFf excludes
xxx string 4 xxxstring 2
```

If you want to match 2nd line that doesn't have corresponding entry in `excludes` then use `grep -v` after pipe:

```
grep -iFf includes file.log | grep -ivFf excludes
xxx string 4 xxxxxxxxxx
```